# URL is not available to Google This page cannot be indexed. Pages that aren't indexed can't be served on Google

Tags: wordpress

URL will be indexed only if certain conditions are met
Discovery
Not checked in live tests
Crawl
Time
22 Oct 2023, 19:36:33
Crawled as
Google Inspection Tool smartphone
Crawl allowed?
Yes
Page fetch
error
Failed: Hostload exceeded
Indexing allowed?
N/A
Indexing
User-declared canonical
N/A
Google-selected canonical

Only determined after indexing

I was faced error
Page cannot be indexed: Not available due to a site-wide issue and Failed: Hostload exceeded. I'm not able to indexing wordpress post on google search console. help me for resolve this problem. Thank you